# Changing value in in all rows, but the highest

Tags: r

I have a table i R with aggregated monthly sales. One of the columns includes information on whether the customer is currently active or inactive. The problem I have is that once the customer is inactive, this affects all previous months, and all the values for that customer is inactive.

I want to highlight what month was the first inactive month, and change all previous months' status too active.

The table looks like this:

```
CustomerID   Month_Yr   TotalSales   Status
   5          05-2016      2         INACTIVE
   5          06-2016      5         INACTIVE
   5          07-2016      1         INACTIVE
   5          08-2016      2         INACTIVE
   6          05-2016      4         ACTIVE
   6          06-2016      1         ACTIVE
   6          07-2016      2         ACTIVE
```

Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Can you show your expected output for the given example?

Comment: CustomerID   Month_Yr   TotalSales   Status
   5          05-2016      2         ACTIVE
   5          06-2016      5         ACTIVE
   5          07-2016      1         ACTIVE
   5          08-2016      2         INACTIVE
   6          05-2016      4         ACTIVE
   6          06-2016      1         ACTIVE
   6          07-2016      2         ACTIVE

Comment: But i can also switch out the entire column with a dummy variable, where 1=INACTIVE. So I would want to change all 1's into 0's, expect the newest date

Answer (score 1):

Do the records end for a customer once the customer becomes Inactive? If so, then this would work.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(id = c(5,5,5,5,6), 
                 status = c("Inactive", "Inactive", "Inactive", "Inactive", "Active"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(status = if_else(row_number() != n(), "Active", status))
```

Comment: Will this still work when the data set contains over 5000 unique IDs?